# reformulating inverse problem as multi-objective optimization

Tags: optimization, pde, inverse-problem

I'm working on an inverse problem for my Ph.D. research, for which I'll write the objective functional as

$J(\theta) = E(G(\theta) - u^o)$,

where $\theta$ are the parameters, $G$ is the forward map from parameters to observations, $u^o$ are the observations, and $E$ is some metric of the error. The forward map $G$ comes from solving an elliptic PDE in which $\theta$ is a coefficient, which for definiteness' sake we'll say is the Poisson equation:

$-\nabla\cdot ke^\theta\nabla u = f$.

In general I'll say that the forward map from $\theta$ to $u$ amounts to solving the nonlinear system $F(u, \theta) = 0$. I've been solving this using the adjoint method so far. This can also be written as a constrained optimization problem

$J(\theta; u, \lambda) = E(u - u^o) + \langle F(u, \theta), \lambda\rangle$

but computationally all the procedures are the same.

What both formulations do *not* exploit is the fact that the forward map is, itself, another optimization problem, i.e. the solution $u$ of the Poisson equation is the minimizer of the Dirichlet energy

$D(u, \theta) = \int_\Omega\left(\frac{1}{2}ke^\theta|\nabla u|^2 - fu\right)dx$.

**Can this inverse problem be reformulated as a multi-objective optimization problem for the pair of objectives $\{E(u - u^o)$, $D(u, \theta)\}$?** If so, is this useful, either for computational purposes or for proving things?

I don't know a lot about multi-objective optimization, so references to any useful literature would be helpful. All I could turn up on a google search for multi-objective optimization and inverse problems were a bunch of papers about genetic algorithms.

Comment: Note that given $\theta$, $D$ has a unique minimizer $u$; and any $u$ that is not a minimizer of $D$ is not a solution to your forward mapping. So there's no room for trade-offs. At best, you could think of this as a bilevel optimization problem -- but, again, since the minimizer is unique and $D$ is convex, you can equivalently replace the lower-level problem with the necessary optimality condition (the PDE). Multi-objective optimization only makes sense if you have two *independent* objectives; one example would be a fitting and a regularization term...

Comment: ... but regularization theory usually (but not always) is the better way of picking the correct balance between fitting and regularization.

Comment: @ChristianClason thanks for the reply, if you rewrite it as an answer I'll accept it. I figured that, if this idea did work, you could eliminate the need for the adjoint state $\lambda$, but I guess it's a dead end. Oh well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

Multi-objective optimization is concerned with the simultaneous optimization of two (or more) competing objectives where you do not wish to decide on the trade-off between the two beforehand. However, this is not the situation you have: Only the exact minimizer of the Dirichlet energy $D$ is a solution to your forward mapping; the actual value of the functional is irrelevant (in particular, any $u$ that does not attain the minimal value is completely worthless). So the only "trade-off" that makes sense is to ensure that $D$ is minimized, and use the remaining freedom (in choosing $\theta$) to minimize $E$. This would lead to a *bilevel* optimization problem ("minimize the minimizer"), but since $D$ is strictly convex and thus admits a unique minimizer, you can equivalently replace the optimization problem for $D$ with the first-order necessary condition $F(u)=0$. This is exactly what you are doing with your Lagrangian $J$ -- by taking the supremum over all $\lambda$, you are enforcing minimality of $D$.

You mention that you would like to eliminate the adjoint state. In principle, you need *some* way of "backpropagating" the difference between state and data back to the parameter space. This is usually provided by the adjoint state $\lambda$; however, if the equation is sufficiently linear in parameter and/or state separately, you might be able to replace the adjoint state with a suitable surrogate. In this context, you might find the following paper useful: http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0266-5611/19/6/010.